# How to use kcbench?

Tags: linux, benchmark

I downloaded `kcbench` according to the online tutorial(https://gitlab.com/knurd42/kcbench). The result displayed after running the script is also correct.

```
Processor:           Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz [48 CPUs]
Cpufreq; Memory:     powersave [intel_pstate]; 128833 MiB
Linux running:       4.15.0-122-generic [x86_64]
Compiler:            gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Linux compiled:      4.14.0 [/home/cuiyujie/.cache/kcbench/linux-4.14/]
Config; Environment: defconfig; CCACHE_DISABLE="1"
Build command:       make vmlinux
Filling caches:      This might take a while... Done
Run 1 (-j 48):       48.92 seconds / 73.59 kernels/hour [P:3022%]
Run 2 (-j 48):       49.33 seconds / 72.98 kernels/hour [P:3006%]
Run 3 (-j 54):       49.15 seconds / 73.25 kernels/hour [P:3022%]
Run 4 (-j 54):       49.24 seconds / 73.11 kernels/hour [P:3018%]
Run 5 (-j 24):       63.12 seconds / 57.03 kernels/hour [P:1861%]
Run 6 (-j 24):       62.87 seconds / 57.26 kernels/hour [P:1862%]
Run 7 (-j 29):       57.96 seconds / 62.11 kernels/hour [P:2191%]
Run 8 (-j 29):       59.04 seconds / 60.98 kernels/hour [P:2141%]
```

But what should I do afterwards? I want to run `kcbench` on a certain core on the server. I read its manual (https://gitlab.com/knurd42/kcbench/-/raw/master/kcbench.man1.md).  When I use `kcbench`, it always appears that `kcbench cannot find a command`. But the previous results show that I should have installed it correctly? What should I do?

Now I tried bash kcbench and it `is feasible`, But how to set `kcbench` to run on a certain core?

Thank you!